# How to replace files in Xcode under version control

Tags: xcode, svn

What's the best way to update some open source classes that are under subversion in Xcode?

For example, I'm using [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) from github in my project and I want to replace my version of it with the latest version.

In the past when I've just imported the new files and deleted the old ones, Xcode/svn has gotten confused and given me error messages about missing files and such.

I'm using Xcode 5.0.1 and allowing it to interface with my local svn repository.

Comment: The files are all within a separate SVN repo, right?  If so, just move the old repo and checkout the new.

Comment: @trojanfoe The entire project, including the Appirater class, is in one local svn repo. I just need to update a couple files. I guess it's really an svn question. I know you can make changes to a file and then commit those changes, but how do you handle it when the entire file needs to be changed because a new version has come out? Short of copying and pasting all the text within, which doesn't seem like the "right" way.

Comment: Put them in separate repos (not sure if you can have sub-repos in SVN) but having two different code bases in the same repo is the root cause of your issue.